# Is there any way to copy the entire EBS & root volume data to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-ebs

I am working on a task to store the entire logs of an instance in a cheaper way both from root volume and EBS storage , so creating an ami or snapshot is not cheap then i came to know that we can store our volume data into S3 but i haven't found anything in the documentation

Comment: If you merely want to store the logs, then why do you wish to copy the entire disk volume?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to simply save log files in S3, then you could use the awscli to [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) those files into S3. There's also a [CloudWatch Logs agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) that can collect and persist them to CloudWatch.